# Returning values from DB laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hey guys I have this:

```
$fetchedUser = DB::table('users')->where('first_nome', $nome)->get();
$f_nome = $fetchedUser->first_nome; return ($f_nome);
```

I want to return a name and maybe some other data of the fetched user. 
But I get an error saying "Trying to get property of non-object"

So I did this:

```
$fetchedUser = DB::table('users')->where('first_nome', $nome)->get(); 
return ($fetchedUser);
```

And I am getting a long array with the fetched user's information from the Database..

So my question is this, how do i return $nome only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$fetchedUser` is an array of users. In order to get only one user (stdObject) you can use `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
$fetchedUser = DB::table('users')->where('first_nome', $nome)->first();
$f_nome = $fetchedUser->first_nome; 
return ($f_nome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert response to array..
Try following format..

```
$fetchedUser = DB::table('users')->where('first_name', $name)->get()->toArray();

 foreach($fetchedUser as $user)
 {
     dd($user['first_name']);
 }
```

Comment: I dont think its neccessary to create a loop, because I only want to fetch 1 row/record